# Catalyst - SKCloudServiceController requestAuthorization always return denied

Tags: ios, swift, macos, ipad, mac-catalyst

First of all thanks in advance,

I'm including support of catalyst on an iPad app. I make use of SKCloudServiceController requestAuthorization on the iPad app and everything works as expected. My surprise comes when I add Catalyst support.

Every time I ask this method it always return `.denied` I reset app permissions by using `tccutil reset All my.bundle` but same. I never get `.notDetermined` state. Catalyst app is running in sandbox mode, Could be something related to this? or am I missing any entitlement?

P.S: I have already included on `info.plist` `NSAppleMusicUsageDescription` entry

Comment: Same for me here. Do you have any news about that issue? For me also access MPMediaLibrary is not working with catalyst.

Comment: No news :( I posted a comment in apple forums

Comment: I can't find your post in the apple forums...

Comment: @Spriter https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/133374

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug was fixed in newest betas

It's now working on **Xcode 12 Beta 4**, but you need to be on **macOS Big Sur beta 4** also

[image: Permission window]

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to disable sandbox mode?

Comment: No, it just require privacy key in plist and you ready to go